# What header contains TickType_t?

Tags: esp32, freertos

```
error: 'TickType_t' has not been declared
```

Which header has this?

FreeRTOS, C++11, ESP32

Comment: Certainly no standard c++ header.

Comment: Yep, exactly why it's tagged FreeRTOS.  Hopefully it helps someone else find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the freeRTOS source tree, add additionally specify the following paths to your compiler:

```
FreeRTOS
FreeRTOS/include
FreeRTOS/portable/<your-compiler>/<your-processor-arch>
```

this happens because freeRTOS header files use relative includes of the form `"FreeRTOS.h"`, if FreeRTOS.h is under `/Src/include/FreeRTOS.h` the compiler needs to have in its path `/Src/include/` , otherwise it will fail to find it.

As far as your question goes, it is defined in portmacro.h, but this file is found under `freeRtos/portable/<your-compiler>/<your-processor-arch>/portmacro.h`
For example if you are compiling with gcc and using an ARM-Cortex4F, it will be under `freeRTOS/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/portmacro.h`

Answer (score -1):

This comes from portmacro.h called from `#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"`